# Solr query doesn't show all the fields

Tags: mysql, solr

I am learning solr (5.5.0) and running in a standalone mode.

Here is the solr-data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/DBN" user="root" password="root"/> 
    <document>
        <entity name="planexample" query="select * from plan where userid=60 limit 3">
            <field column="planid" name="id" />
            <field column="userid" name="userid" />
            <field column="planname" name="planname" />
            <field column="del" name="del" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And I add fields accordingly into managed-schema:

```
<field name="userid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="planname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="del" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"  multiValued="true"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

But when I do query on the webpage of solr, for example, `ip:8983/solr/corename/select?q=del%3A1&wt=json&indent=true` or `ip:8983/solr/corename/select?q=userid%3A60&wt=json&indent=true`, results only show the `id` except `userid,planname,del`, how to make those fields visible in results? And what does the `score` field mean in results?

One example of results:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1,
        "params": {
            "indent": "true",
            "q": "del:1",
            "_": "1461050814466",
            "wt": "json"
         }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "maxScore": 0.90468985,
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "985963",
                "score": 0.90468985
            },
            {
                "id": "1033572",
                "score": 0.90468985
            },
            {
                "id": "1763216",
                "score": 0.90468985
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a `fl` parameter, to get all stored fields,
do `&fl=*`, or a comma seperated list of fields you want i.e.
`&fl=id,userid,planname,del` for example.

Comment: Thank you!  But why do those fields look like they are arrays? {"planname": ["MM"], "userid": [60],"id": "985963","del": [1]}

Comment: Because you have mentioned them as multivalued in your schema.multivalued fields can store multiple values.